# react-native-vector-icons:processReleaseResources FAILED - Ubuntu

Tags: react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-vector-icons:processReleaseResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

I am using **Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit**. After installing react-native-elements and react-native-vector-icons the project build was getting failed with above message. I also noticed that earlier i was using android version 23 and after installing the above 2 react packages, my android version was also updated to 26.

Other questions on same topic did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Temporary Solution**

Go inside your installed project folder. Then inside that go to node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android.

Find file build.gradle

There these 2 properties would be set to 26. Update that to 23 as below:

compileSdkVersion 23

buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

Note: This is a temporary solution cause it's not advised to change the library file.